# Column of NaN created when concatenating series into dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I've created an output variable 'a = pd.Series()', then run a number of simulations using a for loop that append the results of the simulation, temporarily stored in 'x', to 'a' in successive columns, each renamed to coincide with the simulation number, starting at the zero-th position, using the following code:

```
a = pandas.concat([a, x.rename(sim_count)], axis=1)
```

For some reason, the resulting dataframe includes a column of "NaN" values to the left of my first column of simulated results that I can't get rid of, as follows (example shows the results of three simulations):

```
    0         0         1         2

0 NaN  0.136799  0.135325 -0.174987

1 NaN -0.010517  0.108798  0.003726

2 NaN  0.116757  0.030352  0.077443

3 NaN  0.148347  0.045051  0.211610

4 NaN  0.014309  0.074419  0.109129
```

Any idea how to prevent this column of NaN values from being generated?

Comment: can you provide sample data?

Comment: The simulation data was created using pandas.DataFrame(numpy.random.multivariate_normal()) that draws numbers based on certain input parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, by creating your output variable via pd.Series() you are creating an empty dataset.  This is carried over in the concatenation, with the empty dataset's size being defined as the same size (well, same number of rows) as x[sim_count].  The only way Python/Pandas knows to represent this "empty" series is by using a series of NaN values.  When you concatenate you are effectively saying: I want to add my new dataframe/series onto the "empty" series...and the empty series just gets NaN.

A more effective way of doing this is to assign "a" to a dataframe then concatenate.

```
a = pd.DataFrame()
a = pandas.concat([a, x.rename(sim_count)], axis=1)
```

You might be asking yourself why this works and using pd.Series() forces a column of NaNs.  My understanding is the dataframe creates an empty place in memory for the data to be added (i.e. you are putting your new data INTO an empty dataframe), whereas when you do pd.concat([pd.Series(), x.rename(sim_count)], axis1) you are telling pandas that the empty series (pd.Series()) is important and should be retained, and that the new data should be added ONTO "a".  Hence the column of NaNs.